# Is there a way to end idle threads in GNU OpenMP?

Tags: openmp

I use OpenMP for parallel sorting at start of my program. Once data is loaded and sorted, the program runs as a daemon and OpenMP is not used any more. Is there a way to turn off the idle threads created by OpenMP? omp_set_num_threads() doesn't affect the idle threads which have already been created for a task.

Comment: Do you have some code? Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Why is this important? How is this affecting you?

Comment: This is important since I get a very large number of idle threads in the end. I run a copy of my daemon program for each core of the system. On a typical present day hardware it's 48 cores, so I have ~2300 idle OpenMP threads doing nothing. I need OpenMP to speed up restart, I rarely restart all the instances altogether. This is also important since these threads complicate problem analysis with coredumps.

Comment: Vladimir, I have not created an isolated test case, this is the OpenMP code I'm running: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/blob/master/third_party/qsort_arg_mt.c and later on I see OpenMP threads in gdb and in core dumps.

Comment: If you have 2300 idle OpenMP threads on a 48 core system, something is seriously wrong with your code or your environment.  That is not a reasonable situation.

Answer (score 2):

Please look up OMP_WAIT_POLICY, which is new in OpenMP 4 [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fWAIT_005fPOLICY.html].

There are non-portable alternatives like GOMP_SPINCOUNT if your OpenMP implementation isn't recent enough.  I recall from OpenMP specification discussions that at least Intel, IBM, Cray, and Oracle support their own implementation of this feature already.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to trigger the threads' destruction. Modern OpenMP implementations tend to keep threads around in a pool to speed up starting future parallel sections.

In your case I would recommend a two program solution (one parallel to sort and one serial for the daemon). How you communicate the data between them is up to you. You could do something simple like writing it to a file and then reading it again. This may not be as slow as it sounds since a modern linux distribution might keep that file in memory in the file cache.

If you really want to be sure it stays in memory, you could launch the two processes simultaneously and allow them to share memory and allow the first parallel sort process to exit when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, OpenMP has a implicit synchronization at the end of the "pragma" clauses. So, when the OpenMP parallel work ends, all the threads are deleted. You dont need to kill them or free them: OpenMP does that automatically.

Maybe "omp_get_num_threads()" is telling to you the actual configuration of the program, not the number of active threads. I mean: if you set the number of threads to 4, omp will tell you that the configuration is "4 threads", but this does not mean that there are actually 4 threads in process.

Comment: Uhm, no, `omp_get_thread_num` tells you the current thread number, not the number of threads currently executing, nor the maximum number of threads allowed.

Comment: I don't think it kills the threads. The threads are created in a thread pool so they can be used again if needed. This reduces the often significant overhead of creating and deleting threads between parallel regions.

Comment: Edited (i wanted to say "omp_get_num_threads", not "thread_num"